# python - How would i scrape this website for specific data that's constantly changing/being updated?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, request

the website is:
https://pokemongo.gamepress.gg/best-attackers-type

my code is as follows, for now:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re

site = 'https://pokemongo.gamepress.gg/best-attackers-type'
page_data = requests.get(site, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page_data.text, 'html.parser')

check_gamepress = soup.body.findAll(text=re.compile("Strength"))
print(check_gamepress)
```

However, I really want to scrape certain data, and I'm really having trouble. 
For example, how would I scrape the portion that show's the following for best Bug type:

```
"Good typing and lightning-fast attacks. Though cool-looking, Scizor is somewhat fragile."
```

This information could obviously be updated as it has been in the past, when a better Pokemon comes out for that type. So, how would I scrape this data where it'll probably be updated in the future, without me having to make code changes when that occurs.

In advance, thank you for reading!

Comment: too broad question. You could try saving the page and checking the difference. See if that list is available in another format: rss, json, xml.

Comment: @LuisMuñoz I'm just wondering how I can pull that data out in the first place, what would be the correct way of going about it? If I have to update my bot every time that's fine I guess, but I'd definitely prefer to know how to scrape that portion, would I simply change 'strength' with a part of that sentence, or is there a way to find it using html tags?

Comment: you could try writing a parser based on Xpath. This XPath will get a list of all div tags with field__item class: '//div[@class="field__item]'. Parse the list and save to cvs or other format, then use it to compare with future version. Not straight away but a good project if you are really interested :) .

Comment: @LuisMuñoz thanks for your quick replies! appreciate the help. Yeah i was looking into that and using beautifulsoup to search "field__item" as well, but almost everything on that page was using that tag so it returned a lot of information, is there a way to take this a step further to get the exact data I'm looking for? 

I run a bot on discord, and basically, every time someone types !data Water, I want the bot to pull all the information it can about the best water type. For now, I have the bot only giving the best Pokemon for the type.

Comment: perhaps this XPath could work better: '//article[about="/best-attackers-type"]/div/div[@class="field__item"]'. You can try it on the bash command line using xmllint.

Comment: This is a particularly tough one because the tags don't really have many distinct features and are all siblings of one another. However, there are some patterns that can be found in the HTML that you could leverage to accomplish the task.

Comment: @sytech thought so! I thought I might have just been doing something wrong. Aren't the patterns for all the "strengths", etc, the same as well? I guess i'll have to just use soup.body.find again. Thank you!

Comment: @sb2894 I'll post an answer shortly. I think you'll like it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This particular site is a bit tough because of how the HTML is organized. The relevant tags containing the information don't really have many distinguishing features, so we have to get a little clever. To make matters complicated, the divs the contain the information across the whole page are siblings. We'll also have to make up for this web-design travesty with some ingenuity.

I did notice a pattern that is (almost entirely) consistent throughout the page. Each 'type' and underlying section are broken into 3 divs:

- A div containing the type and pokemon, for example `Dark Type: Tyranitar`.
- A div containing the 'specialty' and moves.
- A div containing the 'ratings' and commentary.

The basic idea that follows here is that we can begin to organize this markup chaos through a procedure that loosely goes like this:

1. Identify each of the type title divs
2. For each of those divs, get the other two divs by accessing its siblings
3. Parse the information out of each of those divs

With this in mind, I produced a working solution. The meat of the code consists of 5 functions. One to find each section, one to extract the siblings, and three functions to parse each of those divs.

```
import re
import json
import requests
from pprint import pprint
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def type_section(tag):
    """Find the tags that has the move type and pokemon name"""
    pattern = r"[A-z]{3,} Type: [A-z]{3,}"
    # if all these things are true, it should be the right tag
    return all((tag.name == 'div',
                len(tag.get('class', '')) == 1,
                'field__item' in tag.get('class', []),
                re.findall(pattern, tag.text),
                ))

def parse_type_pokemon(tag):
    """Parse out the move type and pokemon from the tag text"""
    s = tag.text.strip()
    poke_type, pokemon = s.split(' Type: ')
    return {'type': poke_type, 'pokemon': pokemon}

def parse_speciality(tag):
    """Parse the tag containing the speciality and moves"""
    table = tag.find('table')
    rows = table.find_all('tr')
    speciality_row, fast_row, charge_row = rows
    speciality_types = []

    for anchor in speciality_row.find_all('a'):
        # Each type 'badge' has a href with the type name at the end
        href = anchor.get('href')
        speciality_types.append(href.split('#')[-1])

    fast_move = fast_row.find('td').text
    charge_move = charge_row.find('td').text
    return {'speciality': speciality_types,
            'fast_move': fast_move,
            'charge_move': charge_move}

def parse_rating(tag):
    """Parse the tag containing categorical ratings and commentary"""
    table = tag.find('table')
    category_tags = table.find_all('th')
    strength_tag, meta_tag, future_tag = category_tags
    str_rating = strength_tag.parent.find('td').text.strip()
    meta_rating = meta_tag.parent.find('td').text.strip()
    future_rating = meta_tag.parent.find('td').text.strip()
    blurb_tags = table.find_all('td', {'colspan': '2'})

    if blurb_tags:
        # `if` to accomodate fire section bug
        str_blurb_tag, meta_blurb_tag, future_blurb_tag = blurb_tags
        str_blurb = str_blurb_tag.text.strip()
        meta_blurb = meta_blurb_tag.text.strip()
        future_blurb = future_blurb_tag.text.strip()
    else:
        str_blurb = None;meta_blurb=None;future_blurb=None

    return {'strength': {
                'rating': str_rating,
                'commentary': str_blurb},
            'meta': {
                'rating': meta_rating,
                'commentary': meta_blurb},
            'future': {
                'rating': future_rating,
                'commentary': future_blurb}
            }

def extract_divs(tag):
    """
    Get the divs containing the moves/ratings 
    determined based on sibling position from the type tag
    """
    _, speciality_div, _, rating_div, *_ = tag.next_siblings
    return speciality_div, rating_div

def main():
    """All together now"""
    url = 'https://pokemongo.gamepress.gg/best-attackers-type'
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
    types = {}
    for type_tag in soup.find_all(type_section):
        type_info = {}
        type_info.update(parse_type_pokemon(type_tag))
        speciality_div, rating_div = extract_divs(type_tag)
        type_info.update(parse_speciality(speciality_div))
        type_info.update(parse_rating(rating_div))
        type_ = type_info.get('type')
        types[type_] = type_info
    pprint(types) # We did it
    with open('pokemon.json', 'w') as outfile:
        json.dump(types, outfile)
```

There is, for now, one small wrench in the whole thing. Remember when I said this pattern was *almost entirely* consistent? Well, the `Fire` type is an odd-ball here, because they included two pokemon for that type, so the `Fire` type results are not correct. I or some brave person may come up with a way to deal with that. Or maybe they'll decide on one fire pokemon in the future.

This code, the resulting json (prettified), and an archive of HTML response used can be found in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/spyoungtech/d380a18c94de48206f052289f1c1a3e9).

Comment: thank you so much for the great explanation! 

As for the fire types, my bot had an issue creating Embed's initially too, and I did something like this to fix the issue:

cut_gamepress_further = cut_gamepress.split(' & ') then
print(cut_gamepress_further[0]. 

May have to change all my code up now tho to match with your explanation. Thank you again so much! :) So very well explained and flawlessly done!

Comment: No worries @sb2894 . If you have any questions about the specifics in the code, just drop a comment. Cheers and welcome to SO!

Comment: glad to finally be here! Just recently started self-teaching Python 3 and I'm shocked at how awesome this community is!